# How to define LEFT JOIN vars with same name

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get out result from left join where i have same column name
what ever im trying to do always i get unknow column or filed or something else.. where is my mistake ?

Database

oc_damask_name columns

```
id,name,filter_id
```

oc_damask_description columns

```
id,name,filter_id,filter_group_id
```

Query

```
SELECT oc_damask_description.name as ddname, oc_damask_name.* 
FROM  oc_damask_description dd 
    LEFT JOIN oc_damask_name dn ON (dd.filter_id =  dn.filter_id)
```

Error

```
#1051 - Unknown table 'test.oc_damask_name'
```

Comment: Provide info for your DB, please

Comment: Also please provide the Full and Complete error messages

Comment: #1051 - Unknown table 'test.oc_damask_name'

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of your DB ?

Comment: Give each table an alias, e.g. t1, t2 etc, then prefix your field names with the prefix t1.name

Comment: @JonStirling - since it only appears in positions where you could name a table or a view, why do you think it could be a column?

Comment: @JonStirling - when have you seen `<column name>.*` used?

Comment: Nevermind, missed the alias... doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an alias in the `from` clause, that table reference is no longer available under it's original table name in any clause that's logically evaluated afterwards<sup>1</sup>. That includes the `select`. You need to use the alias instead:

```
SELECT dd.name as ddname, dn.* 
FROM  oc_damask_description dd #oc_damask_description no longer exists, dd does
    LEFT JOIN oc_damask_name dn #oc_damask_name no longer exists, dn does
    ON (dd.filter_id =  dn.filter_id)
```

Of course, nothing precludes you from adding a second reference to the same table to the from clause, and if that one is not aliased, the table name is back in scope again but refers to the second reference.

---

<sup>1</sup>This makes SQL aliases somewhat different to other usages of the word "alias", both in everyday life and possibly in other areas of technology. In SQL, an alias *replaces* an existing name, rather than being an alternative name and allowing either name to be used to refer to the same "thing".